# bash eval in if with piped command

Tags: bash, eval, concatenation

piped eval in bash for string length comparison

i am trying to check if a certain device with a given id is plugged in and trigger a action based on that

i tried eval / exec

here is what i have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
KBP='[["lsusb -d 1c11:b04d | wc -c" == "0"]]'
if eval $KBP; then
    echo expression evaluated as true
else
    echo expression evaluated as false
fi
```

expected result:

if device is plugged in and string is not 0 it would hop in the false condition

actual result - cant evaluate the piped condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing fixed expression would look like this:

```
if [ "$(lsusb -d 1c11:b04d | wc -c)" -eq 0 ]; then
```

To remember:

- Bash is spaces aware. `[[` and `]]` needs after and behind (well, `;` is special here, it separates commands).
- To get output of a command use command substitution `$( ... )`
- There is no need for eval here.